# how to use the groovy script with params in logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, groovy, logstash

At first I use the dynamic script to update data to es. But it seems causes memory leak. So I changed the script type to file. I want to get the fields from logstash's filter as params for the script. The question is : how to set params for the script like the elasticsearch's api?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been solved my question.

I'm using variable set by 'script_var_name' which contains the logstash's event itself that can be used in the script.

Hope useful for everyone.

ref:https://discuss.elastic.co/t/update-nested-object-using-script-with-params-in-logstash-elasticsearch-output/49983/13